# Javascript to ASP.NET mvc controller fails using Katana

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, katana

I have a controller. The code is below  The javavascript that works with this controller is also below.  This code was created in Visual Studio 2013 using MVC 5.  The code was published to IIS and has worked as expected for several weeks.  Because of changing requirements the code was ported to a project using Katana and is now self-hosed using a console application. The Controller and javascript are the same.  The issue is that when I make a call to add a location the Get method is called, but the location variable is now null.  Why does this code work hosted in Internet Information Server and not as a self hosted application using Katana?

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PatientCommunication.Model;
using PatientCommunication.Repository;
using PatientCommunication.DataAccess;
using Walden.Utility;

namespace PatientCommunication.Web.Controllers
{
    public class LocationController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/location
        private ILocations locations = new Locations();
        public IEnumerable<Location> Get()
        {
            Database.ReminderConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reminderConnection"];
            List<Location> locationList = new List<Location>();
            locationList = locations.GetLocationList();
            return locationList;
        }

        public void Post([FromBody] Location locationList)
        {
            Database.ReminderConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reminderConnection"];
            locations.UpdateLocation(locationList);
        }

        public ActionResult Put(IEnumerable<Location> location)
        {
            Database.ReminderConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reminderConnection"];
            string toBeVoiced = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                foreach (var loc in location)
                {
                    Location singlelocation = new Location();

                    singlelocation.LocationID = loc.LocationID;
                    singlelocation.LocationName = loc.LocationName;

                    locations.AddLocation(singlelocation);
                }
                return new JsonResult { Data = new { Success = true } };
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                string s1 = er.Message;
                return new JsonResult { Data = new { Success = false } };
            }
        }

        public void Delete([FromBody] Location locationList)
        {
            Database.ReminderConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reminderConnection"];
            locations.DeleteLocation(locationList);
        }        
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#addLocation').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#locationID').val().length < 1) {
        ShowAlert("No Text", "Please Input Location ID")
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if ($('#locationName').val().length < 1) {
        ShowAlert("No Text", "Please Input Location Name")
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    locations.push({
        ID: 0,      
        LocationID: $('#locationID').val(),
        LocationName: $('#locationName').val()
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/location",
        type: "PUT",
        datatype: "json",
        data: $.toJSON(locations),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Data.Success) {
                ShowAlert("Insert", "Record Inserted");
                $("#gridLocations").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                $('#locationID').val('');
                $('#locationName').val('');
                locations = [];
            }
            else {
                alert("Error'");
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  I am using Nancy to deliver static content and in the pipeline I had the call to use Nancy before the call to Web API.  This is what was causing my problem